# Postgres Full Text Search using TSVECTOR and special UTF8 characters

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a database of instagram posts which needs to be searchable. Current implementation uses `TSVECTOR` column and `@@` operator to search against it:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ig_posts (
 /* ... */
 caption_tsv TSVECTOR
);
```

Posts insert SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO ig_posts(caption_tsv)
VALUES (to_tsvector('simple', ?)) /* simple, because post can be in any language */
```

Search SQL:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ig_posts
WHERE ig_posts.caption_tsv @@ to_tsquery('simple', ?)
```

Everything works great, except some posts might contain utf8 encoded bold/italic text, for example:

```
'rosegold':26 'sunshine':23 '':1 '':4 '':2 '':3 '':21 '':17 '':15
```

This causes the `@@` operator to fail, since the "Always" and "" are considered different words. Is it possible to covert bold/italic UTF8 text back to normal within Postgres?

---

Edit: the accepted answer works perfectly, here is the rules file that I used: https://gist.github.com/dsenkus/9250134b338b9862585963dfdf450e13

And the script that was used to generate it: https://gist.github.com/dsenkus/17ddbd29d53bd6dd2cf4051bd05ad44d (generated results requires some cleanup, since some special letters do not exist in UTF8, and 3rd h letter is not recognized, ℎ should be used as value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) contrib module:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

Then you need to create a file `my_unaccent.rules` in the `tsearch_data` subdirectory of the PostgreSQL share directory that contains the character-wise mapping you need. This is something you have to build yourself.

Then you can create a dictionary using it:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY my_unaccent (TEMPLATE = unaccent, RULES = 'my_unaccent');
```

Then you can create a new text search configuration based on `simple` that uses that dictionary:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_unaccent (COPY = simple);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_unaccent
   ALTER MAPPING FOR asciihword, asciiword, hword, hword_asciipart, hword_part, word
      WITH my_unaccent, simple;
```

This full text search configuration should so what you need.